# Ionic error java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified

Tags: ionic2, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to run an app in ionic 2 from github but after running:

```
sudo ionic run android
```

I got:

```
    Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:645)...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/andrea/Desktop/voicedetection/ionic-recorder/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 128

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No match found
```

I already tried the post [Ionic Android build: java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167512/) but with no luck. I also tried to rm/add platform again and I'm sure the android-sdk is linked correctly (version 25.2.3).

Comment: There is no need to use 'sudo' to run ionic commands (run, serve, etc...). Maybe this is your problem. Try to run without it.

Comment: Nope unfortunately it's the same without sudo.